# How can I validate hashmap using esapi?

Tags: java, owasp, esapi

For this code:

```
HashMap temphashMap = session.getAttribute("abc");
```

how can I validate hashmap against the Cross-site Scripting vulnerability using ESAPI ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "validate"?

Comment: I need to validate the Hashmap/Collection against the Cross-site Scripting Vulnerability, Which is the one type of the security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  In order to do validation, you have to know in advance, the special rules and data flows of every single item in that `HashMap`.

How could you tell if one of the form fields in your application was a rich-text field, like the one I used to type this answer?  What if some HTML tags are legal?

You can't know that.

That's why it's 100x more important to make sure data is properly *encoded* for its proper context.

For that you'll use the methods in the `ESAPI.encoder()` class.

The closest thing to what you're asking for would be to set up a servlet filter then on every request/response pair, and then use an XSS filter like AntiSamy to allow certain tags in and disallow others.  However the rules are different for a value used in an HTML attribute, HTML tag text, or a `<textarea>` block.  You would have to write a pretty significant amount of logic for what you could avoid just by escaping all data before you hand it off to another interpreter.